# Hi i need div to be changed when i click on activePage in react-bootstrap Pagination example?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, pagination

```
class ProductTheme extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { activePage : 1 ,Data: "HI"}

    }

  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    switch (eventKey) {
        case 1:
            this.setState({Data:"Hi"})
            break;
            case 2:
            this.setState({Data:"HELLO"+eventKey})
            break;

        default:
            console.log("Hello"+eventKey)
            break;
    }
    this.setState({
      activePage: eventKey,
    });
    console.log(eventKey)
  }
    render(){
        return( 
            <div><NavBar /><section>
            <div className="container" id="PTConatiner">
            <h2>Product Explainer Information</h2>
            {this.state.Data}
             <Pagination

        prev
        next
        first
        last
        boundaryLinks
        items={15}
        maxButtons={2}
        activePage={this.state.activePage}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}
      />
            </div>
            </section></div>
            );
    };
};

export default ProductTheme;
```

hi the above code is working like on clicking next or previous but i don't want to use any switch statements and i too had a look at some npm modules which are available those are not helping my cause can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the expected behavior and the current behavior? Please explain it a bit.

Comment: current the pagination is working and i am expecting it to be when we click on 2 or next it should display the div related to it